# Jekyll latex not showing up in remote but shows up locally

Tags: html, css, ruby, github, jekyll

Jekyll latex not showing up in remote but shows up locally.

I'm using Jekyll minima.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the console :

> WARNING: cdn.mathjax.org has been retired. Check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

For one reason, the temporary redirect to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML is working locally but not on Github pages.

In your ***_includes/head.html***, change

```
https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

to read

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```